# Passing multiple values into a Go to report Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to pass multiple values (Ids - 2,3,4) to a another report in ssrs.  So in the Go to report section of the text box actions I chose the parameter and in the value I gave 2,3,4 but I am getting an error that the parameter is wrong.. What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Typing 2, 3, 4 in the values box is wrong - Reporting doesn't know how to deal with that because it's expecting Integers (or at least one integer) and you're giving it what looks like text but doesn't have quotes so it's confused.

Add a parameter to the report you're on currently. Set the type to "Integer"  and Multiple Values to true, and then go to "Default Values". Select "Specify Values" and then press Add three times, and set the values there like this:

[image: values in parameter]

Once you've done that, right click your text box again and go to Properties, then Action. Click the fx button next to the Values box for the parameter and then go to Parameters menu in the window that opens. Double click the new parameter you created, and the below will appear:

=Parameters!<>.Value(0)

Just delete the (0) from the end of that expression so it finishes in .Value and that should be fine - it'll then pass the three Integers (2, 3 and 4) through to that Parameter in the other report. It should look like this (my Parameter is called LearnerList):

[image]

Hope that makes sense, let me know if not.